# JQuery Click Event Repeats on Next Click in Mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, mobile-safari

I am developing an HTML5 application for a client for their internal use on the iPad platform. Everything has been going very well implementing various JQUERY solutions for a variety of tasks, but this one just doesn't seem to make sense.

They have a list of items on a page, contained in an un-ordered list, which they would like their users to be able to drag and drop to shuffle the order, or click a delete button to remove one of the items.

I have it sorting just fine and it deletes just fine, at first. But then, when testing on the iPad, after I have clicked on the delete button, it runs through a confirm and performs the operation I have defined. But then, the next time I click on the screen in triggers the click event again, even if I am far away from the div which is defined to trigger this event.

Here is an HTML snippet of one of the

tags which sorts and deletes:

```
<li id="12345">
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="product-image">
        <img src="../../img/presentation.png" width="200" height="140" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
        <div class="details">
            <h3><a class="name" href="#">Comparison</a></h3>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Competitor: </strong>[Brand]</li>
                <li><strong>Us: </strong>[Brand]</li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>
        <div class="brand">
            <div class="remove" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">(&times;)</div>
            <div class="edit-bar"><img src="../../img/presentations-edit-bars.png" /></div>
            <p class="logo">[Distributor]</p>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Here are the various jquery includes and the internal javascript to accomplish these tasks:

```
<script src="../../js/libs/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/libs/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/libs/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".remove").click(function () {
            var e = $(this);

            this.style.backgroundColor = "#FFAAAA";

            var p = this.parentNode;
            var count = 1;
            while (p.tagName != 'LI') {
                p = p.parentNode;
                count++;
            }

            var cont = confirm("Are you sure you would like to delete this item?");

            if (cont) {
                var deletedItems = document.getElementById('deletedItems');
                if (deletedItems.value != "") {
                    deletedItems.value += ",";
                }
                deletedItems.value += p.id;
                p.style.display = 'none';
            }

            this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        });
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                var newOrder = "";
                for (i = 0; i < $("#sortable li").size(); i++) {
                    newOrder += $("#sortable li").get(i).id;
                    if (i < $("#sortable li").size() - 1) {
                        newOrder += ",";
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById('currentOrder').value = newOrder;
            }
        });
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be somewhat of a common issue faced by many people. The probable reason is that on the iPad, you have *two* events getting called tap and click.

The solution would be to unbind your events before handling the actual event like

```
$('.remove').unbind('click touchstart').click(function() { ... }
```

Hope this works.